# iOS save/retain data where didReceiveMemoryWarning (Equivalent Android Bundle onSaveInstanceState)

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, bundle, didreceivememorywarning

My question is simple. When do I receive Memory Warning, Where I should save or retain data or states in order to retrieve in `viewDidLoad()`?

For example, I got a view with a TextField, the user write an email and then it do something with another App, my App receives a Memory Warning and I handle it with `didReceiveMemoryWarning` (maybe then, the view will be unload). So, where do I save the "email" in order to set into the TextFiel in `viewDidLoad()` ? Should I save it with Core Data? SQL?

When I use Android and the S.O. is going to remove a View, the method `OnSaveInstaceState` is called and I can save the data into a Bundle, Is there any similar object in iOS?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple things like that, you could save it in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:@"email"];
```

Comment: There are many options for storing objects (CoreData, Plists...), but this is provably the one you want.